# Passar parametro de input para função

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Esbarrei em um problema, para passar o valor do meu input para a minha função sem utilizar `v-model`.

Sei que dessa maneira funciona

```
<Input @click="func" />

func(val){
   alert(val)
}
```

Porem ai eu não consigo passar outro parametro, ex: `<Input @click="func(status)" />`, dessa maneira ele vai receber só o valor que passei, porem gostaria de poder, alem de passar o valor que se encontra no input, mais parametros da minha escolha.

Comment: Do proprio input, se você chama assim `<Input @click="func">` a função já recebe o valor se eu passar o parametro `val` na função, porem se eu passar qualquer parametro no click, não tenho mais o valor.

Comment: @dvd Deu certo, valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode enviar múltiplos parâmetros à função, sendo que `$event` irá enviar as propriedades do elemento, que você pode capturar com `currentTarget`:

```js
var campo = new Vue({
  el: '#teste',
  methods: {
     func: function (a, e) {
       alert(a +"/"+ e.currentTarget.value);
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<Input value="olá!" id="teste" @click="func('status', $event)" />
```